# Get exact mysql cell content using js / jquery / ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I wish to ask about any clues in function construction of the web page. Target is to read one cell from MySQL table, then put it in one cell of web page table. Next, this cell must be self-refreshing each x seconds. Whole web page table will have 25 refreshing columns in 25 rows from the beginning. The Mysql table has 26 columns, but only 25 contains needed and editable data.

A bit of coding:

Main site: web page cell, which will contain refreshing content (now includes non-working and prototype coding)

```
<td>map_loader2(1,2) &nbsp;<div id="whateva"></div></td>
```

PHP request in separate .php file for calling function (only here I'm sure its properly written and working):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$dbname = "map";
$loader="select c$column from map_1 WHERE map_1.RowNumber = $row ";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$result=$conn->query($loader);
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo json_encode($array);
if ($conn->query($loader) === TRUE) {
   // echo "Updated successfully";
   header("Location: http://sectortrader/main_site_editor.php"); /* Redirect browser */

} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Lastly - what I've managed to create after many failed attempts and dozens of different tutorials with countless pages of documentation at W3 with few other sources:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function map_loader2(column, row)
    {
    $("#whateva").load("map_loader_query.php");
    },5000); //refreshing interval
</script>
```

As for now it only refreshes after 5 seconds as intended (however displaying errors - because it doesn't get proper values for query), but I cannot figure out how to force it that to take arguments for the function. I'm quite greeny in PHP and MySQL, and the complete newbie in js/jQuery/ajax. However, this mini-game I'm trying to write is also attempted to improve my weaky skill.

Thanks for spared time.

PS.
I've totally forgot to share which function I've tryied earlier:

```
<?php

function map_loader($column, $row)
    {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "admin";
    $dbname = "map";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    $loader="select c$column from map_1 WHERE map_1.RowNumber = $row ";
    $result=$conn->query($loader);
    $conn->close();
    return $result; 
    }
?>
```

With that I just wished to use it as follows:

```
<tr>
        <td rowspan="25">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>window.map_loader2(1,1) &nbsp;</td>
        <td>map_loader2(1,2) &nbsp;<div id="whateva"></div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
.
.
.
<tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><?php  map_loader(2,1); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php  map_loader(2,2); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
.
.
.
```

And so on, and again, and again once more... Of course, it could be done somehow better - but firstly I wish to make it working, secondly it can be improved. Unfortunately, it wont work so easly as I
 want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must use Ajax to do what you want to accomplish. You need to create a set interval function that will be executed every 5 seconds and then inside it ajax will call the map_loader_query.php page and then success function will return the data. If data queried from the DB is just html, you just need to insert the data queried inside the div whateva or td.

```
<td><div id="whateva"></div></td>    

<script>
    setInterval(function()
    { 
        $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"map_loader_query.php",
          success:function(data) {
              $('div#whateva').html(data);
          }
        });
    }, 5000);
</script>
```